# how to redirect from modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=XXX to domain.eu/XXX?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, redirect

I would like to redirect all url requests with the phpnuke string modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=XXX (xxx is a number) to my domain-name.eu/XXX . How is that possible?

i tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&|)modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=(&.*|)$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1domain.eu/%2 [L,R=301]
```

but it has no effect. Where is the mistake?

Also i don't understand why a simple

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=$1 [L,R=301]
```

doenst work. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I'm seeing this in Drupal questions. But try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/modules\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sid=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.eu/%1 [R=301,L]
```

You can't match everything after the `sid=(.*)` regex part in the URL in most cases. `modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=XXX` and `modules.php?sid=XXX&name=News&file=article` are the same in functionality.

Learned at http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Comment: thank you! It is tagged drupal because it is a drupal installation and a drupal .htaccess file. Unfortunatly the code you suggest does not seem to have any effect. Is it possible that there is something wrong with the RewriteCond?

Comment: when i use

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/modules\.php$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sid=([0-9]*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.eu/%1 [R=301,L]

without the ^ before sid=... the condition matches but i get redirected to domain.eu/XXX??name=News&file=article&sid=XXX